# Java Rest with OkHttp and settings certificates

Tags: java, rest, certificate, okhttp

I'm trying to create my rest service with java and OkHttp3 library but I need equivalent of this settings from Postman:

[Certificates setting in Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KkSUx.png)

In java I'm not able to replicate java code for this configuration. Someone has a solution?

Comment: Please share some code that you have tried.

Comment: Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask